# Outlook 2016 acting strangely; "Favorites" overwritten

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

[As requested, a screen shot added 2/25]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTvkO.jpg)Installed new Outlook 2016 on my desktop PC at home; specs:
AMD A-10-5800K APU with Radeon(tm) HD graphics  3.80 GHz
Installed RAM:  8.00GB (7.20GB usable)
System type:  64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
SPCC Solid State Disk ATA Device: 111GB

I have set up Outlook 2016 to simultaneously display 3 panes:  on the left are my favorites (folders); in the middle is the preview pane; on the right is the reading pane.  Nothing extraordinary about that is there... pretty standard?

So the problem is this, specific to the Folders/Favorites pane on the left... as I read through my emails each day, and sometimes either delete one or MOVE one to another folder, gradually the NAMES of some of the folders start to OVERLAY each other.  Like for example, I will see my TRAVEL folder overlaid suddenly on top of my TRENDS folder.  I can see both names (TRAVEL & TRENDS), but one is partially obscured by the other.  It only happens to folders that are adjacent to (either directly above or directly below each other).  The only way I have found to TEMPORARILY fix this is to close Outlook 2016, wait a minute, then open it again.  That causes the (previously) mixed up overlaid folders to show up in order without the overlayment.

Has anyone else seen this BIZARRE problem in Outlook 2016?  Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix it?

Cheers
OldBaldy (computing since 1966)

2/25/18 In the following image, notice the "Deleted Items" has some other folder underneath it (in the background).  Switching from maximize to minimize or vv does not effect it.  The only way I've found to cure it is to kill Outlook 2016 then restart it.  Thanks!

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful. If you weren't an experienced PC user, I'd suggest accidently dragging one folder into another with the mouse. I've done that more than once myself in File Explorer and hate having to figure out where in Hades I dragged that folder to. Another possibility is the display driver, though I also have a Radeon driver and am not experiencing anything like that in Outlook 2016.

Comment: Does minimizing then maximizing Outlook resolve the problem, even temporarily?